# difference between custom_loss and custom_metric in catboost CatBoostClassifier

Tags: python, scikit-learn, xgboost, catboost

I am trying to learn catboost, and I see two confusing terms with CatBoostClassifier:

`custom_loss` and `custom_metric`.

I have browsed here which says: https://catboost.ai/docs/concepts/python-reference_parameters-list.html#python-reference_parameters-list

custom_metric:
`Metric values to output during training. These functions are not optimized and are displayed for informational purposes only. Some metrics support optional parameters (see the Objectives and metrics section for details on each metric).`

but then what is `custom_loss`?

I see `custom_loss` defined in the R documentation: https://catboost.ai/docs/features/loss-functions-desc.html   - but not in the python one.

yet. on the python [tutorial](https://render.githubusercontent.com/view/ipynb?color_mode=auto&commit=2a1fd8a46d94f5f93672919edb66f568a06c9821&enc_url=68747470733a2f2f7261772e67697468756275736572636f6e74656e742e636f6d2f636174626f6f73742f7475746f7269616c732f326131666438613436643934663566393336373239313965646236366635363861303663393832312f707974686f6e5f7475746f7269616c2e6970796e62&nwo=catboost%2Ftutorials&path=python_tutorial.ipynb&repository_id=138584767&repository_type=Repository#2.1-Model-Training), they have defined a `custom_loss` like so:

```
model = CatBoostClassifier(
    custom_loss=['Accuracy'],
    random_seed=42,
    logging_level='Silent'
)
```

Am I missing something here? Infact, `custom_loss` does not seem to be defined as a property anywhere in the python docs: https://catboost.ai/docs/concepts/python-reference_parameters-list.html#python-reference_parameters-list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I infer the following from [this link](https://catboost.ai/docs/concepts/output-data_loss-function.html) in the documentation.

I am almost certain that they refer to the same parameter, but `custom_loss` is the R name while `custom_metric` is for Python. Apparently they can be used interchangeably as long as they don't cause name collisions.